# WPF Как на одном уровне разместить объекты разных классов?(разные объекты)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, treeview

Доброго времени суток.
На WPF делаю сейчас такое дерево.

**UPD 1**

{

Я хочу получить структуру, как на картинке. Тобишь на одном уровне находятся объекты разных классов и UI видит их как объекты разных классов, а не разные объекты, реализующие один интерфейс.

Идеальный вариант - несколько коллекций, идущих друг за другом.

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сложность в том, что у меня на одном уровне должны находится объекты разных классов. Обычная привязка не подходит:

```
<TreeView Name="TreeListView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTreeObject}" Margin="0,68,0,0" SelectedItemChanged="TreeListView_SelectionChanges">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrTitle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Потому что при биндинге к выделяющимся элементам хочется использовать стандартные средства.

Сейчас делаю так:
Используемая коллекция на этом уровне:

```
public ObservalableCollection<ILeaf> TreeItems {get;set;}
```

Интерфейс:

```
public interface ILeaf
{
    string StrTitle { get; }
}
```

Есть два класса, которые реализуют этот интерфейс.

Далее по SelectedItemChanged отлавливается нажатие на элемент(сделал через Visible на данный момент, чтобы наглядно было).

```
public void TreeListView_SelectionChanges(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if(e.NewValue is BranchRobot)
        {
            this.RobotGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.LAGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        if (e.NewValue is LogicalArchiveDVM)
        {
            this.RobotGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.LAGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Есть 2 Grid(один RobotGrid,другой LAGrid). Они идентичны(кроме Name).

```
<Grid Margin="10,10,386,626" Name="RobotGrid" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeListView}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.503,0.504" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="First Name Robot" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Last Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding StrTitle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="100"/>
    </Grid>
```

И все работает...Два Grid друг в друге и работу через Visible я знаю как убрать.

Мне не нравится подобное отлавливание через SelectionItemChanged.
Можно привязать ViewModel к конкретному View и вызывать его на автомате при выделении(так работало с TabItem у меня раньше. Только наоборот. В коллекции содержался определенный VM, и в зависимости от него подгружался во View Tab Item, привязанный к этому VM).Тут подобное можно сделать.

```
Вопрос:
```

Неужели нельзя, допустим HierarchicalDataTemplate конкретнее(допустим сделать шаблон TreeView, что откуда брать на каком уровне). Или сделать 2 HierarchicalDataTemplate в ItemTemplate, чтобы если была коллекция со вторым именем, он ее выводил по своему шаблону?(так сделать нельзя, я тоже пробовал).

Какие есть еще варианты сделать задуманное?

Как можно детализировать шаблон?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить

Comment: @FoggyFinder я хочу получить структуру, как на картинке. Тобишь на одном уровне находятся объекты разных классов и UI видит их как объекты разных классов, а не разные объекты, реализующие один интерфейса.

Comment: @FoggyFinder добавил UPD 1 и UPD 2. В UPD2 наглядно сравнил, что есть сейчас и что я хочу.

Comment: @FoggyFinder спасибо большое за проявленный интерес. Я нашел решение вопроса. Не подскажете, как лучше изменить вопрос, чтобы люди поняли то, что я хотел?

Comment: не уверен, что селектор шаблонов в данном случае лучшее решение.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под `Они идентичны(кроме Name).` - вы ведь все равно `Name` привязываете, зачем вам два идентичных `Grid`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder это пример был, так то сущности очень разные

Comment: @FoggyFinder точнее в Grid разные поля абсолютно будут, просто в примере они одинаковые.

Comment: теперь я точно запутался, вам нужно просто отобразить выбранный объект? Но ведь есть `SelectedItem` - отображайте его

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67365/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-arantler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос пришел, когда решал другой свой вопрос: [Как задать Шаблон у корня элементов с помощью ItemTemplateSelector в TreeView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733098/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-itemtemplateselector-%D0%B2-treeview/733156#733156)

Как же решить мою проблему:

На уровне, где нужны разные объекты, делаете `List<IViewModel>`. В него подсовываете свои элементы, которые реализуют этот интерфейc. Делаем, как я указано в вопросе выше и добавляем(создавая попутно класс)

```
public class DevicesSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    public HierarchicalDataTemplate Drive { get; set; }
    public HierarchicalDataTemplate Robot { get; set; }
    public HierarchicalDataTemplate Cartridge { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is DriveDVM)
        {
            return Drive;
        }
        if (item is RobotDVM)
        {
            return Robot;
        }
        if (item is CartridgeDVM)
        {
            return Cartridge;
        }


        return null;
    }

}
```

И в SelectTemplate делаем проверку на то, объект какого класса у нас на самом деле и выдаем нуженый DataTemplate. Все.

Далее можно замапить DetailView(по паттерну Master-Detail) отображать в каком-нибудь Frame, в зависимости от выбранного элемента.