# WPF Как задать Шаблон у корня(начала) TreeView? Как задать Шаблон у корня TreeView с помощью ItemTemplateSelector?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Доброго времени суток.

Код TreeView

```
<TreeView Name="TreeListHandDrivesView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding HandDrives}" Margin="0,68,0,394" SelectedItemChanged="TreeListView_SelectionChanges">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>
                    <local:DevicesSelector Drive="{StaticResource DriveDataTemplate}"
                                           Cartridge="{StaticResource CartridgeDataTemplate}"
                                           Robot="{StaticResource RobotDataTemplate}">

                    </local:DevicesSelector>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                <!--<TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <local:DevicesSelector Drive="{StaticResource DriveDataTemplate}"></local:DevicesSelector>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>-->
    </TreeView>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где отмечено синим, должно быть отображение, но его там нет. После проверок стало понятно, что ItemTemplateSelector работает только на вложенные в корень.

Шаблон корня не могу задать(тогда он для всех работает).

Костыль в виде спрятать Корень в Array с одним элементов тоже не хочется. Как быть?

Comment: ...если добавить `mcve` желающих помочь будет больше

Comment: @Ev_Hyper спасибо, но решение пришло через кровь и пот. Если интересно, смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось все чуть проще.
Вот старый код.

```
<TreeView Name="TreeListHandDrivesView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding HandDrives}" Margin="0,68,0,394" SelectedItemChanged="TreeListView_SelectionChanges">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>
                    <local:DevicesSelector Drive="{StaticResource DriveDataTemplate}"
                                           Cartridge="{StaticResource CartridgeDataTemplate}"
                                           Robot="{StaticResource RobotDataTemplate}">

                    </local:DevicesSelector>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

Вот новый код.

```
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
                <!--Вот что добавил.......................................-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="True"></MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="False"></MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/images/Drive/drive.png"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrTitle}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <!--Вот конец того, что добавил.......................................-->
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>
                    <local:DevicesSelector Drive="{StaticResource DriveDataTemplate}"
                                           Cartridge="{StaticResource CartridgeDataTemplate}"
                                           Robot="{StaticResource RobotDataTemplate}">
                    </local:DevicesSelector>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Логика такая. В HierarchicalDataTemplate добавляем шаблон корня, а в ItemTemplateSelector добавляем все используемые HierarchicalDataTemplate нашего деревца.

Притом каждый HierarchicalDataTemplate в себе тоже имеет селектор.

Вот результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ели нужно подробнее, пишите.